# SSH fail into 10.15 OS X Catalina -config?

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, connection

"connection refused" -have done this successfully for years, now with new Mac Mini (with "hardware security"), can't even get close. I have narrowed the question from a recent post: could this be the host config files? (There don't seem to be comparable client files that I can find.) These are the active commands in those (heavily-commented, non-editable) files on the host/remote/server:

-in /etc/ssh/ssh_config:

```
Host *
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
```

--

-in sshd_config:

```
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys
UsePAM yes
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/libexec/sftp-server
```

This is the (names-changed) error output from the command line on the client (local):

```
OpenSSH_7.8p1, LibreSSL 2.6.2
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to yourclient.dyndns.org port 12345.
ssh: connect to host yourclient.dyndns.org port 12345: Connection refused
```

I understand none of that, have tried to look it up without that helping so far.

I could say lots more about trying to open up Privacy, etc., if anyone wishes, but for now: what's with that debug message?

(Anything to do with Terminal using zsh on the host and bash on the client?)

Also, the SSH command I use employs "-p 12345" for added security, and the modem is set for that to forward to port 22, and ... worked fine before the new computer.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Stand down everyone. Suddenly it's working. I did make several minor tweaks but unclear what worked. File Sharing in Apple has switched by default from AFP (port 548) to SMB (445), so that mattered. If anyone wants to know some changes in the Linksys router, just ask.